# Format file from text file in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a file that looks like this:

```
12,1427766557, bob 
22,1427762457, bill 
53,1427769753, bob
```

I'd like to format it like this

```
bob                  bill 
1427766557   12      1427762457   22 
1427769753   53
```

I'm not sure how to approach this. Help please.

Comment: Nothing yet. I'm trying to think it through. Should I go array or hash? I think if I'm pointed in the right direction I can sort it out.

Comment: I thinks you have to use hash of hashes and you have to iterate each hash depending on numbers of elements in hash. And then you have to develop printing logic.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
use strict;
my %data;
while (my $line = <>) {
    $line =~ s/\s+//g;
    my ($n1, $n2, $name) = split(/\s*,\s*/,$line);
    push @{$data{$name}}, [$n2, $n1];
}

foreach my $name (keys %data) {
    print "$name\t\t\t";
}
print "\n";

my $count =0;
my $found=1;
while ($found) {
    $found=0;
    my $line = '';
    foreach my $name (keys %data) {

        if ($#{$data{$name}}>= $count) {
            $found +=1 ;
            $line .=sprintf ("%10d\t%2d\t",@{$data{$name}[$count]});
        } else{
            $line .="           \t  \t";
        }
    }
    if($found) {
        print "$line\n";
        $count += 1;
    }
}
```

should do the job.

HTH
George

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried already?

The command below is not really a "one" liner - and it does require a CPAN module ([`Perl6::Form`](https://metacpan.org/release/Perl6-Form) - which should probably just be called `Perl::Form` and included with `perl`), but it works with a quick cut and paste if you already have the module installed.

```
perl -e '(my @DATA = qq/12,1427766557, bob
22,1427762457, bill
53,1427769753, bob/);
@DATA = map { [ split/,\s*/ ] } map { chomp;  split/\n/ } @DATA;
push @{ $hash{ $_->[2] } } , "$_->[1] $_->[0]" for @DATA;
@header = keys %hash ;
@data = values %hash ;
use Perl6::Form;
print form
"{[[[[[[[[[[[[}   {[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[}", @header,
"{[[[[[[[[[[[[} | {[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[}", @data ;'
```

The command stores your original data in an array/list called `@DATA` (instead of reading from a file or putting it in an `__END__` or `__DATA__` of a script); then uses `map` to `split` it up and `push` it into a `%hash` with the Bob and Bill's names as the hash `key` and the string of numbers as the hash `value`; then it prints things out using `Perl6::Form` (which isn't really needed but which I just like to advertise).

**Output**:

```
bob                          bill
1427766557 12  | 1427762457 22
1427769753 53  |
```

The above could be fairly easily converted into a script which drops the reliance on the `form` command from `Perl6::Format`. If you do that, please post your work as an addendum/edit to your question or as a separate answer. You can answer your own question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. This code assumes that your file is called test.csv.

```
use v5.10;
use boolean;
use strict;
use warnings;  
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = new Text::CSV; 
open(my $f, "<", "test.csv") or die "Can't open file: $!";  
my %numbers_by_name; #hash to hold the data, keyed by name
##
#  read in each line of the file and store each unique line for each 
#  name in the hash
##
while(my $row=$csv->getline($f)){
    my ($num0, $num1, $name)=@{$row};  
    if($numbers_by_name{$name}){
        push @{$numbers_by_name{$name}}, [$num1, $num0]; 
    }
    else{
        $numbers_by_name{$name}=[];  
        push @{$numbers_by_name{$name}}, [$num1, $num0]; 
    }   
}  

##
#  print the header row of names
##
my $num_keys=keys %numbers_by_name;
my $tabs="\t" x $num_keys; 
say join($tabs,keys %numbers_by_name);

##
# the trickier part is formatting the lines of output
##
my $line;
my $i=0;
my $j=1;   
while($i < $j){
    my $more=false;  
    for my $k (keys %numbers_by_name){
        if($numbers_by_name{$k}){
            if($numbers_by_name{$k}->[$i]){
                $line.=join(" ",@{$numbers_by_name{$k}->[$i]});   
            }
        }
        $line.="\t"; 
        if($numbers_by_name{$k}->[$j]){
            $more=true;   
        }
    }
    $line.="\n"; 
    if($more){
        $i=$j;
        $j++;
    }  
    else{
        $i=$j;
    }
}

print $line;
```

Comment: ++ you could always try [`Perl6::Form`](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form) for the "tricky part" - but beware: it is habit `form`-ing ;-)   A bit like [`IO::All`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::All) in that respect - which you could use the read `$csv`.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`this is what I have at this point.

So my hash key contains the third element of the array and the value is the other 2 elements of the array.

12,1427766557, bob

5,1427766556, bill

10,1427766555, bob

```
my %data;
open(DATA, "<", "test.csv") or die "Can't open file: $!";
while (my $row=<DATA>) {
  @$_ = split /(?:,|\s)+/, $row;
  $#$_!=2 ? next : push @{$data{$_->[2]}}, @$_[1,0]
}
```

I just need to read this out so that it will look like this. Help please? I'm hoping to export this as a CSV file.

```
         name        name       name
 time    value       value      value
 time    value       value      value
 etc...
```